# Take a database file from the assets folder

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to get assets file

```
08-12 13:26:33.995: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
08-12 13:26:33.995: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
08-12 13:26:33.995: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14050: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
08-12 13:26:33.995: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:33.995: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
08-12 13:26:33.995: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14054: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
08-12 13:26:33.995: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:34.005: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-12 13:26:34.005: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 407: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-12 13:26:34.005: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:34.005: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-12 13:26:34.005: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 429: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-12 13:26:34.005: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:34.015: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-12 13:26:34.015: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 370: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-12 13:26:34.015: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:34.015: I/dalvikvm(7284): Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-12 13:26:34.015: W/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 372: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-12 13:26:34.015: D/dalvikvm(7284): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-12 13:26:34.115: I/PGA(7284): Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 7284, tid = 7284
08-12 13:26:34.145: I/PGA(7284): New SOCKET connection: com.example.cm (pid 7284, tid 7284)
08-12 13:26:34.155: W/PGA(7284): [7284] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x4a8497a0, 0x0, 0x785bfe78, 0x775bbbe0)
08-12 13:26:34.165: W/PGA(7284): [7284] egl: eglCreateWindowSurface (0x4a8497a0, 0x0, 0x785bfe78, 0x775bbbe0) returned
08-12 13:26:34.175: D/OpenGLRenderer(7284): Enabling debug mode 0
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/Database(7284): Inside getData method.
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/database(7284): open database.
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/database(7284): opening file database.
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteLog(7284): (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteLog(7284): (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.cm/databases/new_12_08.db) - 
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.cm/databases/new_12_08.db'.
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at com.example.cm.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:40)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at com.example.cm.Database.getData(Database.java:50)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at com.example.cm.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4499)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18571)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/SQLiteDatabase(7284):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/AndroidRuntime(7284): Shutting down VM
08-12 13:26:35.485: W/dalvikvm(7284): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5cd36b20)
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/AndroidRuntime(7284): procName from cmdline: com.example.cm
08-12 13:26:35.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7284): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.cm
08-12 13:26:35.485: D/AndroidRuntime(7284): file written successfully with content: com.example.cm StringBuffer : ;com.example.cm
```

Comment: When you ask a question please make sure it is human readable.